# Апликация .NET Core работающая с сенсорами - правильный метод?

Tags: .net-core, embedded, asp.net-core-webapi

Как правильно имплементировать следующую архитектуру:

1. Компьютер с Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 на борту
2. Загружается .NET Web API application (.Net Core 2-3 не важно)
3. Та же апликация считывает данные с разнообразных датчиков, управляет парой сервоприводов и т.д.

Пример архитектуры смотрим на рисунке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно это все организовать?

Моя версия - это запустить таймер при загрузке аппликации и в колбеке всю эту работу с железяками и делать.

Comment: Зависит от железа. Как правило железо прерывает процессор при  каких-то событиях, а драйвер и соответствующий фреймворк умеет отдавать это событие в пространство пользователя. Как дальше вся эта кухня попадает в стек .НЕТ я не знаю, вам виднее.

Answer (score 0):

**UART device** - это, насколько я понимаю, последовательный порт. Работа с ним в .NET Core поддерживается, но нужно подключить пакет [System.IO.Ports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/) (требуемая версия .NET Core - 2.1). Используется класс [SerialPort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8), чтение можно реализовать либо как вы написали, периодическим опросом свойства BytesToRead и последующим вызовом Read, либо подпиской на событие [DataReceived](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8).

**Ethernet device** - если устройство работает по протоколу TCP, используется стандартный класс [TcpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8), тут только периодическая отправка запроса. Если свой протокол, чуть сложнее, нужно использовать [raw sockets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettype?view=netframework-4.8) и реализовать самому этот протокол.

**USB Device** - Если USB устройство работает в режиме эмуляции последовательного порта, все как в первом пункте. Если нет, нужно использовать стороннюю библиотеку, вроде [LibUsbDotNet](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet), или библиотеку от конкретного производителя устройств, если она предоставляется.